# Double complex branch cut integration, how to?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I'm working on a small project of mine, but I have gotten stuck on a particularly challenging integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{x^2+ax+b}}$$
With the condition that $a^2-4b<0$, so all roots will be complex-valued. I'd like to try contour integration around the positive semicircle with center $0$, but I haven't been able to make it work. Even taking branch cuts as the half-lines $[i, \infty]$ and $[\frac{1}{2}\left(-a + i\sqrt{4b-a^2}\right), \infty]$ did not work, as the estimation lemma decides to render every integral around any point to $0$, and the integral over the semicircle itself goes to zero as well, as the denominator contains 2 factors of R. What has gone wrong?[The contour I've chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av3Ic.png). For clarity I've chosen the nontrivial branch point in the first quadrant, but it might at well be in the second. I can't quite figure out where the nonzero value is hiding, as all integrals I evaluate end up being $0$

Comment: Are you committed to a contour integral approach? This looks like an elliptic integral that can be reduced to standard form using real methods.

Comment: I did some research into elliptic integrals, and it seems that you're right, thanks! I do wonder why the complex integration method does not work, but now I can rest easy at last.